# Move question to another SE site

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

Can ["sync too many contacts deletes" and "sync is currently experiencing problems. it will be back shortly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281407/sync-too-many-contacts-deletes-and-sync-is-currently-experiencing-problems-i#) be moved to another site in SE network as it's  a useful resource and top of Google for this error message.

Comment: The top hit for the second error message is [Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly](//android.stackexchange.com/q/96171), not the SO post.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't, because it is way too old.

Only posts < 60 days old can be migrated.

The post is still there and hasn't been deleted; there is no need to migrate it anywhere else.